# Facebook App is neither showing any error nor working properly -PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I am trying to create a very basic Facebook application, Which display 'Welcome' if user is log in and displasy 'log in' button if he is not login. I am following Lynda tutorial, and also took tutorial from Youtube. I have followed these tutorial step by step and write the same exact code written on those tutorial, but still its not working properly. Its neither giving me any out nor displaying desired result.

When I run this program on Facebook it displays LOGIN, and when i click on LOGIN nothing happens, i refresh it and try everything possible but it is not working properly. Kindly check it and guide me.

***-Update Information***

I am running this code from localhost. 
I have update the code. Kindly check this, its still not working properly. When i click on Log in a blank facebook canvas page appears.

```
<?php

require 'facebook.php';

$facebook= new Facebook(array (
'appId'         =>'xxxxxxx',
'secret'        =>'xxxxxxxxxx',
'cache'         =>'true',));


$user= $facebook-> getUser();

    if($user)
    {
        try
        {
        $logout     = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        echo 'Welcome';

        }

        catch (FacebookApiException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();

        }

    }
    else 
    {
        $login= $facebook-> getLoginUrl();

        echo " <a href ='$login'> Login</a> You are Not Login";

    }







?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSession` doesn't exist in the most current Facebook PHP SDK. Your library is many versions behind, so there are most likely more than a handful of errors preventing your application from working.

This is the latest version as of writing this,

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/archive/master.zip

And an example exists at

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php

Also since you are developing locally, it's a good idea to check your error_log.

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. I have updated my Facebook PHP SDK and code, but the same problem is still there. Kindly check it.

Comment: @TahaKirmani until you can get the basic example working which I linked above, it wouldn't make sense for me to check it.

Comment: @TahaKirmani In addition you haven't detailed your error_log. Take the time to detail exactly what is wrong with your app before telling everyone to check it.

Comment: I had already read & watch tutorial of Facebbok New API.It wasnt working thats why i used OLD METHOD. After seeing your link i just pasted my already written code here. My error_log file has not been updated since 26-May-2013. When i run this program from localhost it opens facebook login and after i enter my username & password it shows me following error. `API Error Code: 100 API Error Description: Invalid parameter Error Message: Please migrate to OAuth2 and use new /dialog/oauth endpoint. return_session is no longer available.`

Comment: @TahaKirmani you are still using the Old SDK. The error message explains it. I already told you to update your SDK https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/archive/master.zip

Comment: I have downloaded it again, and place everything in correct order. Now when i open it from `localhost` it works super fine, but when i open `apps.facebook.com/testapptahakirmani` it is still doing the same thing, may it will take some time to propagate all the servers. - Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to pin point the problem from the information you provided but you can try the following.

Wrap any facebook code in a try catch block and see if an exception is thrown:

```
try{

}
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
{
     print_r($e);
}
```

I believe facebook class has a capital 'F'

```
$facebook = new Facebook(
```

Facebook PHP SDK relies on CURL to request data. Make sure that your server has CURL enabled and that you are able to make CURL requests to facebook graph api.

Answer (score 0):

Change your link to

```
echo " <a href='$login'> Login</a>  ";
```

You are missing the =